# Drop Down List with a tree-like look

Tags: asp.net-ajax

give me a example that is use asp.net,sql server,jquery.

I need to build a dropdown that will look like this 
City1
 -Town11
City2
-Town22
-Town33
--Town444
---Town5555
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A "drop-down tree"?  Are you referring to [cascading select elements](http://www.google.com/search?q=asp+.net+cascading+selects)?  Note also that the "SQL Server" part has absolutely nothing to do with the UI.  Where the data comes from is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

[Use ASP.NET AJAX Cascading Drop Down Control to Access a Database](http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/use-aspnet-ajax-cascading-drop-down-control-to-access-a-database)

this may be what you're looking for